# Why I can not remove chars in label?

Tags: c#, winforms, char, label

I try `label1.Text.Remove(1,2);` but it doesn't work.

[image: This is my example]
.

.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Remove` returns new string, does not modify current one, so you need to assign it to label:

```
label1.Text = label1.Text.Remove(1,2);
```

Answer (score 1):

label1.Text is a string and strings are immutable (they cannot change). Think of it as an array of chars. You can't resize arrays without asking for new memory.

string.Remove returns a new, modified string. Simply do `label1.Text = label1.Text.Remove(1,2);`